# Unable to load so file from Java in Eclipse On Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, jna

I have some code that tries to load a C library as follows :-

```
public ThreadAffinity() {
    ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);
}
```

However I get the following error when trying to build the project; The error I get is as follows :-

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libctest': liblibctest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:166)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:239)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:393)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:378)
    at com.threads.ThreadAffinity.<init>(ThreadAffinity.java:11)
    at com.threads.ThreadAffinity.main(ThreadAffinity.java:45)
```

The current working directory is the root of the project and thats where the so file is located. I also tried modifying the LD_PRELOAD variable to point to my so file; however the error persists.

It works just fine on my OSX where the dylib is located exactly where the so file is currently(project root). 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From the exception:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libctest': liblibctest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It implies you used something like:

```
public ThreadAffinity() {
    ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("libctest", CTest.class);
}
```

and not:

```
public ThreadAffinity() {
    ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);
}
```

hence you see the JNA added prefix of lib and postfix of .so added to libctest (liblibctest.so)

Answer (score 1):

`LD_PRELOAD` is used when you want to prefer one particular version of the same shared library over another, which doesn't apply here.

Define `jna.library.path` to point to your project root, and JNA should be able to find it.

Also make sure your library has been built as `libctest.so` and wasn't inadvertently named `libctest.dylib`.